# Calling a function passed as parameter

Tags: common-lisp

Want: If a function or closure is passed, call it, otherwise return the input. I'm trying this:

```
(defun ifcall (x) (if (typep x 'FUNCTION) (funcall x) (x)))
```

and getting "undefined function: X". Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The else-part of your `if` shouldn't be wrapped in parens. When you put something inside parens, it will be treated as a function call. To return the value, simply do

```
(defun ifcall (x) (if (typep x 'FUNCTION) (funcall x) x))
```